# Multithreading issue with sockets

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, actionlistener, runnable

I am currently making a boardgame that allows two player through a socket. I am also trying to add in a game chat, but reguardless I need a way for the Frame class to act as normal (Jbuttons, enter text into a jscroll area, etc) but also send & look for incoming objects. I figured implementing runnable would be the best option.
here is my run method:

```
public void run() {
    while(running){
        Object obj = null;
        try {
            obj = connection.receiveObjects();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            running = false;
        if(obj != null){
            if(obj instanceof String){
                showMessage((String)obj);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

My connection class is just a server or a client, and uses these methods:

```
public void sendObjects(Object obj) throws IOException{
        output.writeObject(obj);
        output.flush();

}   
public Object receiveObjects() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException{
        return input.readObject();
}
```

At the Frame class's constructor I call

```
Thread thread = new Thread(this);  
thread.start();
```

In hopes that the run method will not interfere with the actionPerformed method. But to my dismay, when I click a jbutton (all it does is call the send() method), the program freezes, and nothing is sent over.

Here is the other necessary code:

```
private JTextArea textBox;
private JScrollPane pane;
private JTextArea userText;
private JScrollPane userPane;



private void send(){
    String message = "YOU- " + userText.getText();
    userText.setText("");
    String totalMessage = textBox.getText();
    textBox.setText(totalMessage + "/n" + message);
    try {
        connection.sendObjects(message);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void showMessage(String s){
    String totalMessage = "Opponent- " + textBox.getText();
    textBox.setText(totalMessage + "/n" + s);
}
```

My hope is that once I get the chat working, I can also add in sending over the pieces and calling other methods to do everything else I need (via instanceof). I could probably make a separate class that implements runnable to just deal with data transfer, but I was hoping I could do it all in one class, and do not see why I cannot. I did spend at least an hour and a half looking up multithreading, but I could not figure my problem out. I apologize If I am looking over anything apparent, but mutithreading and sockets are far beyond my comfort zone and AP Comp sci class education.

Comment: You should catch `EOFException` separately and terminate the read loop when you catch it. All other `IOExceptiions` except `SocketTimeoutException` are fatal to the connection; should be logged; and should also terminate the read loop.

Comment: EOFException? I don't think I have any of those, but I'll edit the read loop for the IOException.

Comment: You will get 'one of those' when the peer closes the connection.

Comment: @EJP, I see you around a lot on this site, so I was wondering if you have any idea what is causing my issue with the send thread not sending?

Answer (score 0):

Besides the UI thread, you need:

1. one thread to constantly listen for incoming data
2. one thread to send data

You have #1 but not #2, so modify `send()` method as follows:

```
private void send() {
    // Do the UI tasks on the UI thread
    final String message = "YOU- " + userText.getText();
    userText.setText("");
    String totalMessage = textBox.getText();
    textBox.setText(totalMessage + "\n" + message);
    // Start new thread to do the networking (send data)
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                connection.sendObjects(message);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Comment: Wow, 3 threads? I would never have thought! Thank you! It no longer freezes, but it appears that the message is never received? I put a System.out.print just inside the read loop, and it only prints once, indicating that the message is never sent through

Comment: After some testing this morning, it appears that the connection.sendObjects(message) is never called, or freezes. I put a S.O.P before and after it, and only the before prints...